# stat() in mingw works incorrectly

Tags: c, mingw, stat

I created a simple code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    struct stat eStat;
    int result;
    struct stat eStat2;
    int result2;

    result = stat("g:/temp/dvd", &eStat);
    printf("result=%d | eStat.st_mode=%d | S_IFMT=%d | S_IFDIR=%d\n",result,eStat.st_mode,S_IFMT,S_IFDIR);

    if((eStat.st_mode & S_IFMT) == S_IFDIR)
        printf("It is a dir!!!\n");
    else
        printf("not a dir\n");

    result2 = stat("g:\\temp\\test.txt", &eStat2); 
    printf("test.txt result2=%d | eStat2.st_mode=%d | S_IFMT=%d | S_IFDIR=%d\n",result2,eStat2.st_mode,S_IFMT,S_IFDIR);

    return 0;
}
```

And I compile this code in `VS2010(Windows7, C++)`, output:

```
result=0 | eStat.st_mode=16895 | S_IFMT=61440 | S_IFDIR=16384               
It is a dir!!!                    
test.txt result2=0 | eStat2.st_mode=33206 | S_IFMT=61440 | S_IFDIR=16384
```

I compile this code in `Linux(Debian stable, gcc)`, output:

```
result=0 | eStat.st_mode=16877 | S_IFMT=61440 | S_IFDIR=16384      
It is a dir!!!                 
test.txt result2=0 | eStat2.st_mode=33188 | S_IFMT=61440 | S_IFDIR=16384
```

When I compile in `mingw(gcc) on Windows7`, output:

```
result=0 | eStat.st_mode=6 | S_IFMT=61440 | S_IFDIR=16384           
not a dir                
test.txt result2=0 | eStat2.st_mode=6 | S_IFMT=61440 | S_IFDIR=16384
```

Why does `st_mode` always show 6, When I compile in `mingw`?

Comment: Works fine for me with Dev C++ which uses mingw. What is the compiler version? And are you using any IDE ?

Comment: I compile using cmake version 2.8.7 and mingw gcc-core-4.6.1-2. Are you can compile with mingw gcc? I not used IDE. I try to compile genisoimage on Windows.

Comment: I downloaded mingw from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/Installer/mingw-get-inst/) and it works perfectly fine for me

Comment: I downloaded mingw-get-inst-20111118.exe too. Check please this code with gcc compiller

Comment: I've checked it already and its working, I think you need to check again with the newly downloaded mingw

Comment: I dont have `g:\` directory on my system. I tried with something like `C:/Pavan` and it says "it is a directory"

Comment: I reinstalled mingw. And It is work correctly. I changed mingw header files - it is bad...

Answer (score 1):

What header files did you change to make `stat()` work correctly under `MinGW`?  I suspect results I get from the test

```
stat(path, &stbuf) == -1
```

but I can't be sure because I'm using it in a recursive directory descent and I don't know whether the test for accessibility is (1) correct at that point in the descent, or; (2) retrieving the correct value to check for accessibility.